# Django Rest framework list object has no attribute lower when specifying date format in settings

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to format date fields to d/m/y format. However when I use the below code in the settings file I get the following error: `'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` when performing the get request to fetch the data.
My model field looks like this:

`licence_expiry_date = models.DateField()`

My view looks like that:

```
if qs:
    serializer = vMunGisDogsSerializer(qs,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
raise NotFound(detail='No Data Found')
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date-and-time-formatting

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DATE_FORMAT": ["%d/%m/%Y"],    
}
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  509.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  469.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  480.         raise exc

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  506.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\ylatisrest\erp\views.py" in get
  55.             return Response(serializer.data)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  745.         ret = super().data

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  246.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  663.         return [

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  664.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  515.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

File "C:\django_venv\rest\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in to_representation
  1295.         if output_format.lower() == ISO_8601:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dogs/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser
```

Comment: This error is not due to the date format. Please post your code where the error is generated

Comment: I have added the full traceback if that helps better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the date as a list, Date Format expects a string. Just remove the [ ] brackets from the settings and you are ready to go.